# Why is it recommended to give magic link JWT tokens a shorter TTL than those delivered through HTTP and why one-time?

Tags: hyperlink, jwt, querystringparameter, websecurity, password-less

I'm looking to create an application that never uses passwords and want to understand the risks.

Magic Link guides often suggest giving the JWT token a short TTL and to implement one-time use.

A Compromised email account seems to be a mute point because a password can be retrieved using a password reminder. We already depend on email accounts. Furthermore the security around email is far superior (device recognition for example) than most self-built applications.

Passing the JWT token as a query string parameter is not a risk if you use HTTPS, which I would.

Imposing one-time use means maintaining server side token database - one of the reasons for using JWT is not having to do this.

Adopting passwordless means that every time people want to log in they have to go through the email roundtrip which isn't that great UX but is it acceptable?

Once they have gained access all future auth is managed through JWT as usual.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Passing secrets in a query string is a risk even if HTTPS is used. Aside from that, I agree that JWT makes little sense if you need to store the token as well. JWT generally is a bad choice and shouldn't be your default option.

Comment: Storing a secret string is by far the easiest solution. Not even companies like auth0 can avoid fuckups with JWT, so why would you? https://insomniasec.com/blog/auth0-jwt-validation-bypass

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a refresh token which last longer and an access token for a short period so that the user has to log in few times